# Create Appointment Calendar from Master Spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

We have an old doc that struggles with Excel.  We track his appointments and other pt specific information in Excel.  However, the entire Excel spreadsheet is too complicated for him to deal with.  I'd like to extract a printable daily calendar that would include his appointments for the day and other patient information (i.e., medications, labs etc)  I believe the information is in contiguous columns in the spreadsheet.  My uneducated thought would be to use an If Than Formula (i.e., if date>="today" than copy "cell" to new spreadsheet (or possibly even a word doc)  Sound right?  Any help with the formula would be appreciated

Comment: You might also think about transferring the spreadsheet to .ics format, which can be imported into Google Calendar, Thunderbird, Office Calendar, wtc. See https://en.freedownloadmanager.org/tutorials/how-to-convert-excel-to-ics-calendar-files-with-ms-excel-and-csv-to-ical-calendar-convertor.html

Comment: Thanks... but we would have to still do lots of translation to just get the fragments of information we need